# A strange definition of the ADM mass

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

Given an asymptotically flat manifold $(M^{(n)},g)$ with ends $M_1,\ldots,M_\ell$, we commonly define the ADM mass of each $M_k$ by the following coordinate expression:
$$m_{ADM}(M_k,g)=\lim_{\rho\to\infty}\frac{1}{2(n-1)\omega_{n-1}}\int_{S_\rho}\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}(g_{ij,i}-g_{ii,j})\frac{x^j}{|x|}\overline{d\mu}_{S_\rho},$$
where $S_\rho$ is the coordinate sphere of radius $\rho$, $\overline{d\mu}_{S_\rho}$ is the volume measure induced by the Euclidean background metric, and $\omega_{n-1}$ is the volume of the $(n-1)$-sphere. This definition can be found in most literature. Honestly, I haven't had hands-on experience of calculating this integral, but at least its integrand makes sense to me. By contrast, I have no idea what is going on in an equivalent definition. In his book *Geometric Relativity*, Dan A. Lee defines
$$m_{ADM}(M_k,g)=\lim_{\rho\to\infty}\frac{1}{2(n-1)\omega_{n-1}}\int_{S_\rho}\left(\overline{\mathrm{div}}g-d(\overline{\mathrm{tr}}g)\right)(\overline{\nu})\ \overline{d\mu}_{S_\rho}.$$
As before, all barred quantities are computed using the Euclidean background metric, and $\overline{\nu}$ is the Euclidean unit outer normal. **My question is**, how do we compute $\overline{\mathrm{div}}g$, the divergence of $g$? It is completely insane for me to talk about the divergence of a quantity that is **NOT** a vector field. Is it really possible to define such entity?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, divergence is defined whenever you have a connection, for all types of tensors. You surely have seen divergence of tensors before if you have written down Maxwell's equations or the stress-energy tensor and their conservation laws! As a quick intro, the divergence of a (contravariant) tensor is defined as the contraction of the derivative index with some upstair index. If it is covariant (as $g$ is) you should rise some index before, in this case using the metric itself, of course. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#The_divergence_of_tensors)

Comment: You can define it geometrycally to be $\mathrm{trace}_{\bar{g}} \left( X\mapsto \bar{\nabla}_X g\right)$. Note that it is taken with respect to the euclidean metric $\bar{g}$ on $M_k$

Comment: Thank you guys. I was wondering if you could help me with the integral. I'm trying to prove they are equivalent, but little do I know about $S_\rho$. Is it a real sphere in a Euclidean space? I mean, what exactly is $\overline{\nu}$? Thank you.

Comment: Just notice that $\bar{\nu}  = \frac{x}{|x|}$ is the unit radial vector field, and since $\bar{g}$ is the euclidean metrics, in the cartesian coordinates, the covariant derivative coincides with usual partial derivatives. With this, it is clear that $(\bar{\mathrm{div}}(g))(\bar{\nu}) = g_{ij,i} \frac{x^j}{|x|}$, and $d(\bar{\mathrm{trace}}(g))(\bar{\nu}) = g_{ii,j}\frac{x^j}{|x|}$.

Comment: @Didier You've always been helpful, but how do you interpret $$\int_{S_\rho}\cdots\overline{d\mu}_{S_\rho}?$$ Is it an integral over the submanifold obtained from the inverse image of $S_\rho$ under the asymptotically flat coordinate chart $\Phi_k$? Thank you.

Comment: @Steve Not quite, since the volume element on $S_\rho$ is the Euclidean one, not the one induced by $g$. It's just a surface integral over the Euclidean sphere. You can think of the integral as taking place in Euclidean space, where $g$ is just some other $(0,2)$ tensor.

Comment: @Kajelad Thank you, but how do I do with the integrand $$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}(g_{ij,i}-g_{ii,j})\frac{x^j}{|x|}?$$ Its argument is ranging over a subset of $M$, not a subset of a Euclidean space! That's where I am stuck.

Comment: @Steve $g_{ij}$ denotes the local representative of the spacetime metric $g$ in the flat chart. This is an object on the coordinate domain $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\overline{\mathbb{B}^n}$, not on $M$.

Comment: @Kajelad I'd like to hazard a doubt on that. We write $g=g_{ij}dx^i\otimes dx^j$ on the coordinate neighborhood, so each $g_{ij}$ is a smooth function on that neighborhood and accordingly a function on a subset of $M$.

Comment: @Steve It's commonplace in this setting to use the notation $g_{ij}$ interchangeably to denote the smooth function $U\subseteq M\to\mathbb{R}$ and its coordinate form $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\overline{\mathbb{B}^n}\to\mathbb{R}$. Here's its more useful to think about it as the latter.